# How to change js variable on updated php response

Tags: javascript, php

How would I go about changing a defined variable in a js script that is running when a specific php session variable response is returned?

How would I change the color within this canvas js array when a specific php session variable is set.  The method I am using now is leading to a problem of increasing the speed of the animation though the color does change.

```
   <div id="isohold">  
<canvas id="iso"></canvas>
<div id="loghold">Login</div>
</div>   

  <?php
    session_start();                
    //3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];


    echo " <script>

'use strict';


var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;
var sp = rn(1, 5) / 10000;
iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: 0.0005,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - 0.0005;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + 0.0005) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>    
<script>
                 $(\"#loghold\").hide();   
</script>       
            ";
    }else{
    echo "<script>

'use strict';

var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;

iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: rn(1, 5) / 5000,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - el.speed;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + el.speed) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>          
            ";           


  };

 ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: added the array that I am trying to change a single variable from when a php session variable is set in a seperate div

Comment: "when a php session variable is set in a separate div" does not make much sense. PHP session data can be updated at the moment when your page is being processed at the server, or when an async request has been sent and appropriate data received back... and maybe your page updated as a consequence. However, it's still super unclear what exactly you want.

Comment: okie so I have a canvas js running that displays a colored wheel of sorts.  Thats where the array is from.  I have a login system that uses ajax and php so that the whole page does not need to reload on logging in(this part works fine), I am trying to make it so once someone logs in and a specific session variable is set the color variable in the canvas js changes

Comment: I will update with my present php/js code that I believe to be terribly ineffecient as its leading to a speeding up of the canvas animation on reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php $color="yellow"; ?>     <!--define it in php-->

    <div id="color" data-color= <?php echo $color; ?> ></div>    <!--insert it in html-->

    <script>
    var color="";    //declare your variable in JS
    window.onload = function(e) {
    color=document.getElementById("color").dataset.color;     //redefine the variable's value from the html defined by the php
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: I will work with this response in a bit.  I thank you for the clarity of the response

Comment: Or just var color="<?php echo $color ?>";